# is it possible to set the event id when using okhttp-sse to send and recive a event request

Tags: java, spring-boot, okhttp

I am using okhttp-sse to recive the sse message, now I want to relate the request and response, before the sse request, I stored the request info into database, when sse send back events, I want to composite the response information and stored with the request together. I am facing a problem that I did not know how to relate the request and response. this is my code looks like:

```
 public static void okHttpEvent(SseEmitter emitter, String prompt, String openAiKey) {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://chat.example.top/v1/chat/stream/completions?q=" + prompt)
                .build();
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public Response intercept(@NonNull Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        Request original = chain.request();
                        Request request = original.newBuilder()
                                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + openAiKey)
                                .header("Accept", MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM.toString())
                                .method(original.method(), original.body())
                                .build();
                        return chain.proceed(request);
                    }
                })
                .connectTimeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .build();

        RealEventSource realEventSource = new RealEventSource(request, new EventSourceListener() {

            @Override
            public void onOpen(EventSource eventSource, Response response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onEvent(EventSource eventSource, String id, String type, String data) {
                try {
                    SseChatService.getInstance().appendMsg(data);
                    emitter.send(data);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    emitter.completeWithError(e);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onClosed(EventSource eventSource) {
                emitter.complete();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(EventSource eventSource, Throwable t, Response response) {
                emitter.completeWithError(t);
            }
        });

        realEventSource.connect(okHttpClient);
    }
```

what should I do to send a event id or other fields and the sever response the uniq fileds so that I could make the request and response related? is that possible? this is the dependencies I am using:

```
// Okhttp
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.3"
// Server Sent Events
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-sse:4.9.3"
```

this is a relay function, request to the openai server using sse and relay the message to the client side using sse. And store the question and answer into the server side database. I have already tracing the function and found the onEvent message id is null, then I  tried to find the official document how to send a uniq id and recieve the same id, but did not found any clue.